# Is there any way to extract assets.car in linux based systems?

Tags: python, c, objective-c, shell, go

I need to extract an Assets.car (compiled form of assets catalog), but I can't use private frameworks because my code runs on linux based systems.

I have found many tools that do the work, but they are all MacOS based (using CoreUI.framwork headers).

How could I get the images from Assets.car file?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `Assets.car` has an idiosyncratic, undocumented format.  All the tools around it are macOS- or iOS-based because those are the only environments in which such files are commonly created or used.  You can find more information here: https://blog.timac.org/2018/1018-reverse-engineering-the-car-file-format/.  I'm afraid, however, that your question seems to amount to a request for tool recommendations, and those are off-topic here.

Comment: I'm rather looking for a script more than closed polished tool.